# Gradle dependencies that were declared without a version failed to resolve

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, java-8

I  am doing `gradle clean build` have my java class

```
        @SpringBootTest  
        class DemoApplicationTests  {
       @Test
        void contextLoads() {
        }
     }
```

**error**: cannot find symbol
            **@Test**
             ^
      symbol:   class Test
      location: class DemoApplicationTests
    **Deprecated Gradle features were used** in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.

**build.gradle**

```
    buildscript {
       ext {
          springBootVersion = '2.2.2.RELEASE'
       }
       repositories {
          mavenCentral()
       }
       dependencies {
          classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
       }
    }
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

    group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8 

    repositories {
       mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
       compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
       testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    }
```

*Simply downloaded the the basic springboot starter kit - but will not compile, maven build itself took some effort*

**Update**
Fixed the gradle file with correct group `com.example` (cut-n-paste mixup). Now error has changed:

```
one or more dependencies that were declared without a version failed to resolve:
    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:

Did you forget to apply the io.spring.dependency-management plugin to the demo project?


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:.
     Required by:
         project :
```

Added this also, but still same error:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.2.RELEASE'
}
```

Thx

Comment: surely there's more to it... it's a simply dependency problem most probably.

Comment: Post your `build.gradle` as otherwise nobody could help.

Comment: Added build.gradle to main post.

Comment: Also fixed build.gradle with correct group `group = 'com.example'` . Now the error changed also updated in main.

Comment: What is this `sourceCompatibility = 1.8`

Comment: Go to https://start.spring.io. Select your dependencies. Thengenerate a project. You'll get the correct build file, applying the required plugins (you're missing the dependencies plugin).

Comment: @JB Nizet : Yes thats worked, I had originally created a maven project and added 'my own'  build.gradle - so that was the issue - all kinds of compatibility

Comment: Had map to port 8081, compiled and finally started. But now **Whitelabel Error Page**  This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.`

Comment: Changed to `@RequestMapping("/")` instead of `@RequestMapping(value = "/")` and it worked. *(New to this - so however it works)*

Comment: The error is explicitly telling you what you need to do -> *Did you forget to apply the io.spring.dependency-management plugin to the demo project?*. As you can see you don't have that plugin (the spring boot plugin isn't the dependency-management plugin!).